# How can I ban a user in on_event? | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Really simple question, just need to know how to ban a user in `on_event`.

Thank you!

Comment: Given the member, try ```await member.ban(reason='banned')```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just put

```
await member.ban(reason="any reason here")
```

inside the event listener if you're using cogs.
So if you want to ban a member right when they join (the first event listener I could think of), you can just put

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def ban_on_join(self, member):
    await member.ban(reason="Joining the server")
```